# Windows Phone App back button blank screen

Tags: windows-phone

I am developing a Windows app where I have login screen and from there I am navigating to different pages depending upon user's access rights. This bit is working fine. But when user click back button on phone it shows blank screen. I think reason for this is because I am not on MainPage.xaml it is on another page and by clicking back button it come back to mainpage where it has nothing to show. I may be wrong.

Has any one faced this problem Please help me because I am ready to put my app on live this is the only problem I am facing.

Answer (score 0):

If your mainPage is log in page and you are navigating from main page, after successful log in remove main page entry from back stack. So that it will exit the app instead of showing blank page.

For removing entry from Page stack you can use following.

`this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();`

Please check around before you post question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did look around may be could not get right answer its not always easy to get what you are looking for. Back to your answer it works but I have logout option as well. So If I use this.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry(); click on back button works great but when user clicks on logout app tries to navigate to mainpage but this is not working. Can you please help?

Comment: Sorry another question How do I unload all the xaml pages from history. The problem is when user is pressing logout from a page it shows logout screen to them but clicking on back button takes them to previous page which I think still in cache for some reason. Is there a way to clear everything when user clicks logout. Sorry for this direct question I am in desperate situation and thought may be you solve my this problem.